# causation correlation and constraints

Tags: causation, causality, reason

We know causation doesn't imply correlation and correlation doesn't imply causation.
I was curious to know does constraints implies correlation or causation.
If A constraints B and B constraints A does bidirectional constraints imply anything?

Comment: Your described constraints are geometric in nature thus cannot be called causation which is an essentially physical concept with cause always preceding its effect if they really exist...

Comment: @DoubleKnot could you explain the relation between geometry and causation if exist any...

Comment: As already hinted above their exact relationship can be said to be not unlike math and physics. Colloquially cause and effect certainly exists in our physical world and lies at the heart of the inside of (light) cones where colloquial causality rules. And one myth is the cones are folded in such a way that causality would be preserved for all valid observations where its boundary is light-like which we never experienced…

Comment: The question is completely misguided. Of course causation implies correlation.

Comment: I think this may be important to clarify for some people: correlation doesn't PROVE causation, but correlation can absolutely be used to draw reasonable inferences about probable causative relationships. If someone says "the water in this town is infected with lead, and now everyone's dropping dead", and another person says "well correlation doesn't imply causation", it's the second person who's being unreasonable, not the first.

Answer (score 1):

Your premise that “causation doesn’t imply correlation” is wrong. Causation definitely implies 100% correlation. For example- coronavirus originated in China and then it spread worldwide.
Movement of coronavirus from China can be correlated with the point of origin with 100% certainty.

However “correlation doesn’t imply causation” is sometimes true as the real cause can not be discerned therefore we can make a guess with some statistical level of confidence.

If A constraints B and B constraints A then it implies that at least they are correlated. If A implies B and B implies A then they are causally connected.

Comment: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/100373/causation-vs-correlation

Answer (score 0):

Constraint is the counterpart of causation, preventing some effects from happening.

If A causes B then A constraints everything else from happening. Just like causation also constraints work only one way. There are no bidirectional constraints and therefore no implications.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what your question means, but if you are asking what additional constraints are needed for a correlation to qualify as a causal relation, then there is no simple answer because there are many theories of causation.

People have tried to understand causation in terms of regularities, probabilities, counterfactual conditionals, interventions, processes, mechanisms, explanatory theories, forms and substances, and more. There are also some outlier views such as Leibniz's preordained harmony and outright skepticism.

Furthermore, a correlation between A and B allows for many different causal relations. Maybe A causes B, or B causes A, some third thing C causes both, or each causes the other in a circular fashion. It could also be more complex and involve many factors. It could also just be a case of random error, or of systematic error.

What we can reasonably say is that some common features seem to be a requirement for A to cause B, although there is plenty of room for uncertainty.

1. Temporal precedence. Causes precede their effects.
2. Proximity. Causes are physically close to their effects. Newton's theory of gravity was criticised for holding that gravitational attraction works at a distance, and Newton acknowledged this as a difficulty.
3. Mechanism. We often distinguish correlation from causation based on knowledge of a mechanism. It was known back in the 1930s that smoking is correlated with lung cancer, but it took many years of scientific research to demonstrate that smoking causes lung cancer. The main difference is that we now understand the mechanism by which smoking results in cancer.
4. Counterfactual dependence. In typical cases at least, if A causes B this supports the counterfactual conditional that if A had not occurred then B would not have. There are some exceptions and complications, but by and large this holds.
5. Explanatory value. This is harder to make precise, but usually when we say A causes B we are trying to explain why B happened. This accounts for why we often focus on one specific component of a cause and call it 'the cause'. If an aeroplane crashes and we enquire what caused it to crash, we do not want to be told that it was gravity. We knew that already: we want something specific, like a bird strike or pilot error or an equipment failure. Also this helps to explain why a negative or an absence of something can be a cause. What caused these flowers to die? Nobody watered them. Why won't my car start? There's no fuel in the tank.

Answer (score 0):

You can have "A if and only if B" without A causing B or B causing A.

In the following example you have A and B with a common causation. Consider a a sequence of falling domino tiles with a bifurcation like this:
[image]
here is a schematic view:
[image]
falling of tile O causes (and let's suppose it is the only possible cause) a chain of falling tiles resulting in A and B falling as a final effect.
You have "B falls -> O falled -> A falls" and also "A falls -> O falled -> B falls" but A falling didn't cause B to fall,